# c# Splitting a string based on number of characters

Tags: c#

I'm looking through the functionality of the Split ability of Strings in c#, and I was wondering if there was a way that I could split a string based on number of characters rather than a specific delimiter?

For example, can I split "cat dog" in a way that would fill the first 7 slots in an array, since there are 6 characters and a space.

Or is it required that you specify a delimiter to split on?

Comment: The title would imply that you want, for example, a string array in which the first value is the first 5 characters, the second is the next 5 characters, etc. so that you have a fixed with delimiter instead of a character delimiter.  Is that what you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for [`String.ToCharArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x.aspx)? That creates an array of characters...

However, bear in mind that `string` already supports both iteration and indexing anyway:

```
// Print every third character
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i += 3)
{
    Console.WriteLine(text[i]);
}

// Print each character
foreach (char c in text)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

Comment: Ah, I suppose that is what I was looking for. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

There is no built-in method that does this; you'll need to write it yourself.

If you want an array of *single* characters, you can simply call `.ToCharArray()`.

Comment: +1 There should be badge got "asked question and get answers from people with more than 800K in reputation total" :)

Answer (score 0):

`string.Substring( int startIndex, int length )` might help, if you need to split into chunks of more than one character.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aka44szs.aspx